# How does どうなったら work here?

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension

好きになるってどんな感じ?

どうなったらその人を好きだと判別するの

It's not　どうやったら. In the first sentence he asks "How does it fell to fall in love" but what about second one?

Comment: Are you familiar with the verb なる? If you are, how exactly do you get stuck breaking it down?

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking, どうやったら and どうなったら are both interrogatives for the cause/reason/condition of something. But やる means "to do", and なる means "(for a situation) to turn out; to end up". Therefore, どうやったら assumes the cause is someone's action ("how can you ～", "by doing what"), whereas どうなったら assumes the cause is a natural phenomenon or an objective condition ("under what condition ～").

- どうやったら燃えるんだろう？
  How can we get it to burn?
  What do I need to do to make it burn?
- どうなったら燃えるんだろう？
  Under what conditions will it burn?
  What has to happen for it to burn?

> どうなったらその人を好きだと判別するの？
> Under what conditions can I determine that I like that person?

どうやったらその人を好きだと判別するの ("How can I make it judge?") sounds like there is a special method just for starting judging, but that's not natural.